# Cassandra: 6 node cluster, RF=2: What to do when 2 nodes crash?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

Good Day

We have a 6 node casssandra cluster witha replication factor of 3 on our keyspaces. Our applications make use of QUORUM so we can survive the loss of a single node wihtout it affecting the application.

Lets assume I lose 2 nodes at the same time. If my application was using consistency level of ONE then it would have been fine and my application would have run without any issues but we would like to keep the level at QUORUM.

My question is if 2 nodes crash at the same time and I do a nodetool removenode for each of the crashed nodes, will the cluster then rebalance the data over the remaining 4 nodes (and getting ir back to a 3 replica) and if done should my application then be able to work again usinng QUORUM?

Answer (score 0):

In title you write RF=2, in text RF=3. You did not specify Cassandra version and if you are using single-token or vnodes. Quorum CL means, in a RF = 3 that 2 nodes must write/read before returning. It is possible that you face minimal issues/no issue even if 2 nodes dies, it depends on how many common ranges (partitions) the nodes shares.

Give a look at [this distribution example](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeDistribute_c.html) that is exactly like the one you describe: RF3, 6 nodes.

**using single tokens:**
if you loose couples like (1,4) - (2,5) - (3,6) -- your cluster should allow all writes and reads, no issues. A good client will recognize nodes down and won't use them anymore as coordinators. Other situations, for example loss of nodes (1,6) might lead to a situation in which any r/w of F and E tokens will fail (assuming an equal distribution about 33% r/w operation will fail)

**using vnodes:**
here the situation is slightly different and also depends on couples you loose -- now if you repeat the worst scenario above -- you loose couple of nodes like (1,6) only B tokens will be affected in r/w operations since it's the only token shared between them.

Said that, just to clarify the possible scenarios, here's your answer. Nodetool removenode should be used like explained in [this document](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_remove_node_t.html). Use removenode **IF AND ONLY IF** you want reduce the cluster size (here what to do if you want [replace a dead node](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_replace_node_t.html)). Once you did that your application will start working again using Quorum since other nodes will be responsible for partitions previously assigned to a dead node.

If you are using the official Datastax Java Driver you might want to let the driver temporary fight your monsters specifying a [DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.html)

HTH,
Carlo